# removing handles from a moen 6010 bathroom faucet and install 1224 cartridge

Tags: bathroom, faucet, plumbing-fixture

I have a moen 6010 bathroom faucet assmbly. No screws visible to remove the cartridge. How do I get the handles off to gain access to the cartdridge?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Have you tried looking at the [installation guide](http://www.moen.com/shared/docs/instruction-sheets/ins10586.pdf) or [exploded parts diagram](http://www.moen.com/shared/docs/exploded-parts-views/6010pt.pdf)?

Comment: https://www.moen.com/customer-support/installation-help/1224-cartridge-replacement-tutorial